# Matploltib quiver plot: argument order

Tags: python, matplotlib, calculus

Given a 2D array of aspect values (compass bearings e.g. as represented by the aspect derivative of an elevation model), I'm creating a [quiver plot using matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html). This is being placed over a coloured matrix of the aspect values to act as a check.

The code is working in that it creates what I want but only where the arguments are opposite to what I expect. I'm making a simple mistake but can't spot it.

---

**QUESTION:** Although `matplotlib.pyplot.quiver()` expects `quiver([X, Y], U, V, [C], **kw)`, why does my code only give the expected answer where `quiver([X, Y], V, U)` (i.e. U and V are the other way around) is used?

---

Incidentally, when plotting, I've shifted the origin of `plt.imshow` to `lower` (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648379/python-matplotlib-quiver-wrong-orientation)). I think the problem lies somewhere related to my indexing etc.

Code below (using python 3.5 and matplotlib v3.x):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def compassBearing_to_standardPosition__degrees_counterClockwise(bearing_deg):
    """Vector magnitude and direction calculations assume angle is relative to the x axis 
          i.e. 0 degrees north is at 3 o'clock
    Adjust compass bearings to be relative to standard position
    """
    std_pos=(450 - bearing_deg) % 360
    return(std_pos)

def calculate_U_and_V__vector_magnitude_and_direction(angle_degrees, magnitude=1):
    """Calculates the components of a vector given in magnitude (U) and direction (V) form
    angle: Expected that angles are in standard position 
            i.e. relative to the x axis or where 3 o'clock is zero and not the compass bearing 
            where 12 o'clock is 0
    magnitude: defaults to 1
    """
    angle_rad=np.deg2rad(angle_degrees)
    x = magnitude * np.cos(angle_rad) # change in x == U
    y = magnitude * np.sin(angle_rad) # change in y == V
    return(x,y)

def array_indices(arr, indexing='xy'):
    """Calculates index positions of each cell in array
    These can be used to map to e.g. when creating a quiver plot

    indexing: Giving the string 'ij' returns a meshgrid with
        matrix indexing, while 'xy' returns a meshgrid with Cartesian indexing.
        In the 2-D case with inputs of length M and N, the outputs are of shape
        (N, M) for 'xy' indexing and (M, N) for 'ij' indexing.
    """
    nrows, ncols = arr.shape
    nx = 1
    ny = 1
    x = np.linspace(0, ncols-1, ncols)
    y = np.linspace(0, nrows-1, nrows)
    #y = np.linspace(nrows-1, 0, nrows) # note that the largest vlue is first
    xi, yi = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing=indexing)
    return(xi, yi)

#Create a toy aspect grid (degrees North)
aspect_grid=np.array([[ 216,  226,  151],
       [  74,  323,  268],
       [ 177,  204,   84]])

#Get the array indices
x,y=array_indices(aspect_grid, indexing='xy')

#Get U and V 
x_change,y_change=calculate_U_and_V__vector_magnitude_and_direction(aspect_grid.flatten())

#Plot quiver over imshow
cmap = 'twilight_shifted' # this will expect matplotlib v3.x
plt.imshow(np.floor(aspect_grid), cmap=cmap, origin='lower')
plt.colorbar(label="Aspect (degrees N)")
plt.quiver(x, y, y_change, x_change, pivot='middle') # <<< why not x,y,x_change,y_change?
plt.title("Surface aspect values")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass your `aspect_grid` array into `calculate_U_and_V__vector_magnitude_and_direction` you aren't converting them from absolute bearing to counterclockwise degrees since `compassBearing_to_standardPosition__degrees_counterClockwise` is not being called in `calculate_U_and_V__vector_magnitude_and_direction`. Due to the 90-degree misalignment of the two conventions this leads `cos(angle)` to correspond to the `y` component and `sin(angle)` to correspond to the `x` component (due to the property `cos(x - pi/2) == sin(x)`). In order to correct this you simply need to use the conversion you have set up (which does correctly convert from bearing to standard position) by doing something like

```py
#...
angle_degrees = compassBearing_to_standardPosition__degrees_counterClockwise(angle_degrees)
angle_rad=np.deg2rad(angle_degrees)
#...
```

in `calculate_U_and_V__vector_magnitude_and_direction`. This will then allow you to use

```py
plt.quiver(x, y, x_change, y_change, pivot='middle')
```

and get the correct result:

[image]